# How to implement next page action as built in maps apps in iphone from apple

Tags: iphone, google-maps

In iPhone, Map application, Right corner button, that is next page animation button, Can we impletement this button action, Is it animation? Can you explain more in details.

Thank you,
Madan Avulagadda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like that look into UIView animations, however I believe that specific one is still an undocumented animation.  So if you want your app in the store, you can't use it.